# Material component Bottom App Bar change back icon color and slide up programatically

Tags: android, material-design, material-components, material-components-android

I am implementing the Bottom App Bar (https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/) and I am facing two challenges.

1. When using the `Navigation` component and navigate to a new fragment, the drawer icon turns int `<-` back button but it is black. Any way to change its color?
2. If I set the behavior to 
   `myAppBar.hideOnScroll = true`
   then when I am in a Recyclerview and I scroll up, the bar gets hidden which is really nice. However, if I navigate to a new fragment, the bar remains hidden. How can I programatically show the bar again?

LE: 1. was fixed by using android:theme `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: The BottomAppBar can now be scrolled on or off the screen programatically. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111925683**

For now you could just set or animate the translationY property of the `BottomAppBar` to be 0. And perform the animations run by the `BottomAppBar.Behavior` on the fab: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/841ba156fc33e721b991684c8a4bb4afdc56d90c/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar.java#L754-L782